# Javascript Display Selected Image

Tags: javascript, image

I have another Javascript problem that I could really use help with. Again I am sorry for such silly questions but I am really new at this and I just have no idea what I am doing. I have the code so far of what I need and then notes in the script for the information I am missing.

Thank you!

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
//build a function named displayImage
//it should be catching the value of the item selected in a variable named whichImage
//use an if / else structure to test for whichImage not being equal to the string "noImage"
//if the statement is true then display the selected image in the canvas image
//if the statement is false then display the "blank.jpg" external file in the canvas image

//In the select tag below add an onChange event handler that calls the displayImage function
//the value property of the selection list should be passed to the displayImage function as it is called
//hint (this.value)

function displayImage(whichImage)
{
    if(whichImage != "noImage")
    {
        document.canvas.src = whichImage;
    }
    else
    {
        document.canvas.src = "blank.jpg";
    }
}


</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<form name="imageForm">
<table border=3>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="imageSelector" onchange = "displayImage(this.value)">
    <option value="noImage">Select an Animal
    <option value="dog.jpg">Dog
    <option value="cat.jpg">Cat
    <option value="parrot.jpg">Parrot
    <option value="fish.jpg">Fish
    <option value="alligator.jpg">Alligator
    <option value="mouse.jpg">Mouse
    <option value="fox.jpg">Fox
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="blank.jpg" name="canvas">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just want us to do your homework/assignment for you?

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Change to a option on click image with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183391/change-to-a-option-on-click-image-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using jQuery for this, try:

```
$('select[name="imageSelector"]').change(function() {
    var whichImage = $(this).val();

    // It would make more sense to have the noImage option's value "blank.jpg" instead of using an if statement here
    if(whichImage != 'noImage'){
        // Also give the img tag an id instead of just selecting it with a name attribute
        $('img[name="canvas"]').attr('src', whichImage);
    }else{
        $('img[name="canvas"]').attr('src', 'blank.jpg');
    }
});
```

I followed the details in your comments here but there are a few things that could be done better (see my code comments).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes I have actually tried do this on my own before even asking here. I am taking a 5 week JavaScript class that is online only. He is trying to make us learn from the book but it is much more complicated that I had hoped. I am really grasping the concept of HTML and CSS but that is probably because I am in a face to face class for this one. Is code academy worth looking into to better grasp the JavaScript concept? I feel like I am a bright person I just dont learn well from just reading something.

Comment: @EllenHarris if that question or any other was helpful to you make sue to vote/accept the Answer. It's a way to say "thanks" here on StackOverflow. Happy coding.

Comment: @EllenHarris I'm just the same Ellen I can't learn anything from just reading. I would really recommend doing a course in Javascript and maybe even PHP if you have the time.

Comment: So I have used idea from what both of you gave me and I have made it further but still not there. Trying to use his whichImage function. I updated my code for you to see.

Comment: Instead of doing 'document.canvas.src', add an id to your image and use 'document.getElementById("canvas").src'

Comment: So do I need an individual id for all of my images? I am really sorry if that is a stupid question.

Comment: @EllenHarris you cannot vote cause you have not enough reputation points, but you can hit `V` to accept the desired answer.

Comment: Yes try id="animal" and document.getElementById("animal").src

Comment: Also close your option tags!

Answer (score 0):

Or if it has to be pure javascript ignore older IE browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <title>My img</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="imageForm">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="imageSelector" id="imageSelector">
    <option value="blank.jpg">Select an Animal
    <option value="dog.jpg">Dog
    <option value="cat.jpg">Cat
    <option value="parrot.jpg">Parrot
    <option value="fish.jpg">Fish
    <option value="alligator.jpg">Alligator
    <option value="mouse.jpg">Mouse
    <option value="fox.jpg">Fox
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="blank.jpg" id="canvas" alt="Showing the selected image">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>

var img={
  imgEl:document.getElementById("canvas"),
  sel:document.getElementById("imageSelector"),
  changeHandler:function(){
    img.imgEl.src=img.sel.options
      [img.sel.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(img.imgEl);
  },
  init:function(){
    img.sel.onchange=img.changeHandler;
  }
};
img.init();



</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```